# rust vector iterator in multi-layer loop

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, range, slice

I try to use iterator on vector slices, but it just doesn't work.

My code are as follows

```rust
  pub fn three_sum(nums: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {
        let mut res: Vec<Vec<i32>> = Vec::new();

        for (n1, &i1) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
            for (n2, &i2) in nums[(n1 + 1)..].iter().enumerate() {
                for (n3, &i3) in nums[(n2 + 1)..].iter().enumerate() {
                    if i1 + i2 + i3 == 0 {
                        res.push(Vec::from([i1, i2, i3]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I expected the n2 loop in nums ranging n1 to the end, but it just loop from the beginning, regardless of what n1 is.

Same happened on n3.

Did I use iterators and slices correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate), enumerate just counts the number of iterations. If you want to skip the first `n` elements of an iterator, you should use the [`skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) function instead, which also more clearly expresses your intent.

```rust
nums.iter().enumerate().skip(n)
```

Note the order of `enumerate` and `skip` however: this way you're first constructing an enumerated iterator, then skipping some elements, so your index will also "start from" `n`. The other way around you'll skip th elements first, then count them, starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for `enumerate` to know where you want to start counting from so it always starts at 0.
You can use `zip` with a range if you want to start counting from a different number.

```rust
pub fn three_sum(nums: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<[i32;3]> {
    let mut res = Vec::new();

    for (n1, &i1) in nums.iter().enumerate() {
        for (n2, &i2) in (n1+1..).zip(nums[(n1 + 1)..].iter()) {
            for (n3, &i3) in (n2+1..).zip(nums[(n2 + 1)..].iter()) {
                if i1 + i2 + i3 == 0 {
                    res.push([i1, i2, i3]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Comment: that's a good method!